# VBA code for button to copy data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for some help with a button, I have got data in cell A1 that i need to paste in to a different cell once i'm done at the end off the day.

In cell B1:B6 I have Monday to Saturday I'm looking to make a button to copy the data for A1 to Monday i have made a button to clear A1 when i have finished at the end of the day ready for the next day.

I will need to button to update the data at the end of each day and stay under that day once i push the clear button the next day to start again.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Recording a macro and viewing/editing the generated code?

Comment: I was thinking of doing this but I'm not to sure how that would work.

Comment: Well, until you're stuck on a *specific* programming issue, this site can't help you. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```vba
Sub CopyDataByDay()
    Dim data As Range
    Dim today As Date

    Set data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    today = Date

    If (Weekday(today) = vbMonday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbTuesday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbWednesday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbThursday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbFriday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B5") = data.Value
    ElseIf (Weekday(today) = vbSaturday) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B6") = data.Value
    End If

    data.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes thank you i was working on something like this but as this is at work i was unable to see it. I know now where i went wrong i was missing the vb at the start of the day thank you once again

Comment: You're welcome.  Make sure to check it as the correct answer if that is indeed what you needed (I need the rep).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim IWeekday As Integer

    IWeekday = Weekday(Date(), vbMonday)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        If IWeekday <> 7 Then .Offset(IWeekday -1, 1).Value = .Value
        .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```